# Border/Margin/Padding not 0 when specifically set 0

Tags: html, css, padding, margin

I have a simple question where my the stuff in my div are not without margin.
Specifically, when set margin, padding and border all to 0, there is still whitespace between  elements

Code:

```
<div id="menu" >
<a href="#" style="margin:0;border:0;padding:0;background:red">sup</a>

<a href="#" style="margin:0;border:0;padding:0;background:red">sup</a>

</div>
```

Just by adding these codes to an empty text file and saving as html, there is white spaces between the elements, unless I specifically set a negative margin. This would work, but I just want to know why is it not 0 when it is specifically set to 0.

Thanks in advance :D

---

New finding :

I was trying to make the above into display:block to display one on top of another just when I found out that

upon adding this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
```

It did not work

I was supposed to use this doctype but it does not work now.

Any solutions?

---

The code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<div id="kingmenu"  style="position:absolute;top:90px;left:290px;width:55px;">
<a href="#"><img src="http://white-attic.com/themes/prestashop/img/kingtop.png"></a><a href="#"><img src="http://white-attic.com/themes/prestashop/img/kingbottom.png"></a>
</div>
```

problem is as shown in this screencap:
http://img828.imageshack.us/img828/8331/whitespace.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whitespace is in your markup.

Even if you set the `a` elements to `inline-block` (which they are not by default), you would still see the (normalized) space that is there in your HTML.

To eliminate this you have to "butt" the elements up against one another.

UPDATE: Your file should now look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<div id="menu" ><a href="#" style="margin:0;border:0;padding:0;background:red">sup</a><a href="#" style="margin:0;border:0;padding:0;background:red">sup</a></div>
```

I have checked in Chrome, Firefox 6 and IE 8 that there is no space between the links.

Comment: so is there any method to eliminate the whitespace other than setting a negative margin?

Comment: Eliminate it in the source: run the `<a>` tags one immediately after the other.

Comment: @robobooga, in which browser?  Presumably this means you switched out of quirks mode, but I did not find the `DOCTYPE` to have any effect.  See edit.

Comment: it works horizontally, however, if I want to do it vertically, it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Probably what you're seeing is the result of `line-height`.  keep in mind that these are inline elements.  I reproduced the look (I think) you're getting, and this rule should fix it: `a { display: inline-block; height: 100%; }` (Obviously modify the selector as needed.)  This has the added benefit of allowing wrapping when the `a` series is wider than its container.

Comment: I have updated the question with the screen capture and my codes.

Comment: And the only other way I could think of is to use a table instead

Answer (score 2):

This is because basically you're just adding a space. `Div` is a block element and `a` is a inline element, so basically both inline elements are spaced.

Remember that Browser interpret spaces.

Answer (score 1):

That's because a new line in HTML is interpreted as a space when it is rendered.

Try this:

```
<div id="menu" >
<a href="#" style="background:red">sup</a><a href="#" style="background:red">sup</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, but by adding the doctype as said in my question. your method does not work. but if I remove the doctype, it works perfectly. Is there any workaround?